# Is there a Windows C++ API to validate Windows username/domain name is a valid account on the local machine (without the password)?

Tags: c++, windows, validation, msdn, user-accounts

I am trying to validate whether given username/domain name entered by the user is a valid user on the machine, i.e. If a local user account exists for that user on the given machine. 
(I do not require all Active Directory users. I just want the users who have at least logged into the machine once.)

[LogonUser API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378184(v=vs.85).aspx) helps me in validating username/domain name and password combination, but it does not tell me if username/domain name is valid if I do not have access to the password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
BOOL IsValidUser(LPCWSTR username)
{
    LPUSER_INFO_0 info = NULL;

    NET_API_STATUS result = NetUserGetInfo(NULL, username, 0, reinterpret_cast<LPBYTE>(&info));

    NetApiBufferFree(info);

    return result == NERR_Success;
}
```

Though, note that if this function returns false, it does not mean that the username is invalid. There could be other reasons [NetUserGetInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370654%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) does not succeed.

(Terribly ugly API.)

Comment: Does the API NetUserGetInfo  work for domain users on local machine? I see it works for local machine users. For domain users it tries to reach the server. 

I tried that and it seems it doesn't work for them. Even "Net User"command only lists down local user and not the domain user.